# Library/Tool to extract word coordinates from a pdf

Tags: java, pdf, coordinates, highlighting

I am looking for a (preferably Java-) library or a command line tool to extract word coordinates from pdfs. The input-pdfs contain either text or images with ocr-text in behind.

My Use Case:
In a Java web-application I would like to use this to do hit highlighting and present this without additional software (e.g. Adobe Reader etc.). Instead I want to convert the the matching pages into images and present them within a web page.

Comment: iText won't render PDFs.  It can find text & coords (within the limits of such things within PDF), but can't draw your images for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use http://pdfbox.apache.org/ to do the highlighting and present them as pdf itself. Also look at http://itextpdf.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPedal to generate the thumbnails (http://www.jpedal.org/pdf_thumbnail_tutorials.php) and extract the text (http://www.jpedal.org/support_egETAW.php)